# SQL syntax to calculate total menu items per meal orderID across multiple meal orderIDs

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL and Stack overflow and have a question about SQL Server syntax.  i have searched online but I am not finding what I need and I would appreciate your assistance in this matter.

I have data in a source table for meal orders (each with a specific ID (e.g. 12345C) and items of each order (e.g. sandwich, drink, chips), each with an associated number starting with 1.  For instance, the sandwich would have an item number of 1, the chips would be item # 2, and the drink would be item # 3 for the same orderID 12345C. The prior example would therefore have 3 rows of data in the source table for orderID 12345C.

My questions are these:

1. how do I use a SQL expression to determine the number of items per each order (e.g. 3 for the above example, which is also the maximum value for item number for each orderID)
2. and then add all of these items per order across hundreds of orders per day to determine the daily total number of items ordered.

So, if I had 3 orders in one day -  one with 2 items, the second with 3 items, and the third with 4 items, I would like my final number to be 9.

This number is for use in a Sisense dashboard that allows SQL syntax in the field definition.  Thank you for your help!

It is a bit difficult to explain but I am not able to use a query from a table because I am working with a dashboard in Sisense so I am adding fields in a pivot display and one of the fields I would like to include is the total count of order items per day (across several dozen orderIDs).

Here is an example of the data in the table: from the example I would like the final answer for orderID 1787588 to be 3 (there are 3 items within the order).

Comment: Why isn't the answer just to simply count the total rows in a day?

Comment: If you coud show a sample of the SQL table will be helpful. From your question I understand that you have a row per item, am I right?

Comment: Thank you both for your prompt responses!  Tab, I guess I was counting the wrong field (the max of the itemID) and your suggestion worked when I counted the individual items.  Much appreciated!